# NSDateFormatter Memory leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

With the help of Instrument I found that the following section of the code leaking memory.
Instrument saying  NSDateFormatter leaking memory here.

```
- (NSDate*) dateSelected{
if(selectedDay < 1 || selectedPortion != 1) return nil;

TKDateInformation info = [monthDate dateInformationWithTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
info.hour = 0;
info.minute = 0;
info.second = 0;
info.day = selectedDay;
NSDate *d = [NSDate dateFromDateInformation:info timeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];


HolidayAppDelegate *delegatObj = (HolidayAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

NSDateFormatter  *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd-yyyy"];

    // below line getting leak
NSString *message = [[formatter stringFromDate:d] retain];
delegatObj.selecteddate=message;
NSLog(@" selectd %@ ",delegatObj.selecteddate);
[delegatObj getholiday_forcalnder];

return d;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: dude try to add your language also in your tag...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change these lines

```
NSString *message = [[formatter stringFromDate:d] retain];
delegatObj.selecteddate=message;
```

by these lines

```
 NSString *message = [formatter stringFromDate:d];
  [message retain];
delegatObj.selecteddate=message;
[message release];
```

also selected date is property which is of type retain so don't call directy retain on it. It increases the retain count.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the retain on message. It will be owned by the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you

```
- (NSDate*) dateSelected
{
if(selectedDay < 1 || selectedPortion != 1) return nil;

TKDateInformation info = [monthDate dateInformationWithTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

info.hour = 0;

info.minute = 0;

info.second = 0;

info.day = selectedDay;

NSDate *d = [NSDate dateFromDateInformation:info timeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];


HolidayAppDelegate *delegatObj = (HolidayAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

NSDateFormatter  *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd-yyyy"];

NSString *message = [formatter stringFromDate:d];

delegatObj.selecteddate=message;

NSLog(@" selectd %@ ",delegatObj.selecteddate);

[delegatObj getholiday_forcalnder];

[formatter release];

return d;
}
```